# OpenCV 2.4.9 for android issues on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV 2.4.9 for android on Eclipse. I have followed the steps online to try and set up the sample projects that come along with the opencv 2.4.9 sdk. When i build the project i am getting the following error

```
resource '/opencv library - 2.4.9/bin' does not exist
```

I have already installed ADT, CDT plugins and configured NDK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what path have You set to the NDK? `/opencv library - 2.4.9/bin` is a path to root directory of linux system. I doubt that is the place where You keep the NDK. It should be `/home/<user>/<path to ndk>` or might be in `/opt/`.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that project.properties target was set to a version different from the sdk I had installed. Changing this solved the problem.